# ereg_replace code

Tags: php, preg-replace, ereg-replace

i updated my php to 5.3 and i have a problem with my ereg_replace

```
$txt = ereg_replace("<(/)?(font|span|div|del|ins)[^>]*>","",$txt); 
$txt = ereg_replace("<([^>]*)(class|lang|style|size|face)=(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^>]+)([^>]*)>","<\\1>",$txt);
$txt = ereg_replace("<([^>]*)(class|lang|style|size|face)=(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^>]+)([^>]*)>","<\\1>",$txt);
```

if i change the `ereg_replace` to `preg_replace` i get the warning :

Message: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier ']'

could someone help me fix the preg_replace

Comment: Why are you changing from `ereg_replace` to `preg_replace` at all?

Comment: ereg_replace() is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you don't have pattern delimiters at all. You need to add them.

Try this

```
$pattern1 = '#<(/)?(font|span|div|del|ins)[^>]*>#';
$pattern2 = '#<([^>]*)(class|lang|style|size|face)=(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^>]+)([^>]*)>#';
$txt = preg_replace($pattern1, '', $txt);
$txt = preg_replace($pattern2, '<\\1>', $txt);
```

Better yet though, would be to not use regex at all to try to parse HTML like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$txt = preg_replace("~<(/)?(font|span|div|del|ins)[^>]*>~","",$txt); 
$txt = preg_replace("~<([^>]*)(class|lang|style|size|face)=(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^>]+)([^>]*)>~","<\\1>",$txt);
$txt = preg_replace(~"<([^>]*)(class|lang|style|size|face)=(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^>]+)([^>]*)>~","<\\1>",$txt);
```

I've been added delimiters(~) to this expressions. Try.